# Travis-CI node build failing randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js, travis-ci

I have a problem with one [node module](https://github.com/SoftwareMarbles/nock/tree/fix-travis-build) on which all tests are working locally, on other boxes and on Travis-CI but sometimes, and not due to a timeout, one single test fails on [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/SoftwareMarbles/nock/builds). The test is deterministic, at least according to me, so it shouldn't fail randomly.

I've traced the problem to this part:

```
function record(rec_options) {

    //  Originaly the parameter was a dont_print boolean flag.
    //  To keep the existing code compatible we take that case into account.
    var typeof_rec_options = typeof(rec_options);
    var dont_print = (typeof_rec_options === 'boolean' && rec_options)
      || (typeof_rec_options === 'object' && rec_options.dont_print);
    var output_objects = typeof_rec_options === 'object' && rec_options.output_objects;

...

        var out = !output_objects ?
          generateRequestAndResponse(body, options, res, datas) :
          generateRequestAndResponseObject(body, options, res, datas);
```

For the value of `rec_options` being `{ dont_print: true, output_objects: true }`, `var output_objects` is evaluated (again only *sometimes*) as `false` so the function outputs strings and not objects upon which the test, correctly, fails. The proof that the flag evaluation fails can be seen in [this build](https://travis-ci.org/SoftwareMarbles/nock/jobs/19522596) which dumps out string instead of objects (also I have a test to ensure that the returned value is an object whenever `output_objects` is specified and that fails as well showing `string` where `object` was expected).

According to me this should never happen and `output_objects` is not defined ambiguously and certainly not randomly. And yet this is exactly what happens time after time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that sometimes the **whole** test suite runs without error and sometimes it does not? Does the problem correlate with a specific version of node?

Comment: Yes, sometimes the whole test suite runs without an error. And other times this one test that covers the code above fails. All other tests (hundreds of them) always pass. It first appeared that the problem was on node 0.8 but later on 0.10 also failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in one of the unit tests that wasn't waiting for its async call to finish before finishing itself. This would then interfere, depending on the timing, with execution of other tests. This is very specific to the node module in question ([nock](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nock)) as it mocks HTTP/HTTPS requests and thus subsequent tests would sometimes capture the async requests from the faulty test.